# How can I slow down ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

Is there a way to slow down ansible by placing a "sleep 5 seconds" between every server run.

For example, I would require something like that:

```
# --sleep-in-between is a hypothetical flag that would easily explain what I'm looking for
ansible production_servers -a "systemctl restart network" -f 1 --sleep-in-between 5secs
```

So, if production_servers is a group of servers: `server_1`, `server_2`, `server_3` then the above command will perform the following:

```
Output:
server_1: Executing systemctl restart network
sleep 5 seconds
server_2: Executing systemctl restart network
sleep 5 seconds
server_3: Executing systemctl restart network
sleep 5 seconds
```

I need automation to take place slowly so that I can observe the system for any glitches taking place in the monitoring system while ansible is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: **"*Is there a way to slow down ansible by placing a "sleep 5 seconds" between every server run?*"**

A: Yes. It is. Use [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html#wait-for-waits-for-a-condition-before-continuing) module and set [serial](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#using-keywords-to-control-execution) to 1. For example

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: systemctl restart network
    - wait_for:
        timeout: "{{ sleep_in_between|default(5) }}"
```

By default, each host will wait 5 seconds before termination. It's possible to set it from the command line. For example, sleep for 10 seconds

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e "sleep_in_between=10" playbook.yml
```

Comment: I just wish there was a command line flag that would help in running adhoc ansible commands instead of writing a playbook to handle the sleep interval.

Comment: IMHO, this won't happen. The flow is controlled by [strategy plugins](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/strategy). There is no mechanism to pass command line flags to plugins.